# how to compile boost thread library

Tags: c++, boost

I want to compile only the thread and regular expresession library of boost and I want both static and dynamic libs. Could you please let us know how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use bjam to build libraries. Just invoke it in your boost folder.

With parameters

> bjam toolset={your toolset}
>   variant={release|debug}
>   threading=multi link={static|shared}
>   {library name}

Just replace values from {} with values of your choice. For toolset name you can check {your boost dir}\tools\build\v2\user-config.jam (you can set your toolset there and you will don't have to write it in command line).